# source updating in wpf binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF window and give it a DataContext, when targets change it work well (by using `UpdateSourceTrigger`), but when one of DataContext properties (source) change, the target doesn't update. Is there any way to force target binding update when source updates? Is there something like `ObservableCollection` for one item ?

This is my class:

```
public class PaymentDetailInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Payment Payment
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return 100 * Payment.ConsideredValidNormalOverTime / 60;
        }
    }
    public int SumOfInvalidNormalOverTimePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return 100 * Payment.ConsideredInvalidNormalOverTime / 60;
        }
    }
    public int SumOfOverPriceConst
    {
        get
        {
            int _sumOfOverPriceConst = 0;

            if (!Payment.ValidNormalOverTimePriceIsPercent)
                _sumOfOverPriceConst += SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice;

            if (!Payment.InvalidNormalOverTimePriceIsPercent)
                _sumOfOverPriceConst += SumOfInvalidNormalOverTimePrice;

            _sumOfOverPriceConst += Payment.RewardPrice;

            return _sumOfOverPriceConst;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

}
```

Some elements in my Window are bound to `Payment` of `PaymentDetailInfo` (payment is a database table), so as an example user can change `Payment.ConsideredValidNormalOverTime` then `PaymentDetailInfo.SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice` will change and then `PaymentDetailInfo.SumOfOverPriceConst` will change. But target that is bound to `PaymentDetailInfo.SumOfOverPriceConst` does not update even though the datacontext of my form is updated.

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your data class to update target bindings. This is standard way of updating target using MVVM.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:***

Now **Payment** is passed to **PaymentDetailInfo** at construction. **PaymentDetailInfo** wraps the properties of **Payment** so you can create your binding on **PaymentDetailInfo** alone.

I've made the setter of **SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice** private. I think this should work but I haven't tested it.

```
public class PaymentDetailInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

/// <summary> The payment model.
/// </summary>
private Payment _model = null;

/// <summary> Constructor.
/// </summary>
public PaymentDetailInfo(Payment payment)
{
    _model = payment;
}

/// <summary> Wrapper around Payment.ConsideredValidNormalOverTime.
/// </summary>
public int ConsideredValidNormalOverTime
{
    get { return _model.ConsideredValidNormalOverTime; }
    set
    {
        _model.ConsideredValidNormalOverTime = value;

        // make sure to set the property and not the backing field, otherwise OnPropertyChanged won't be 
        // called and the value of _sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice will be incorrect
        SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ConsideredValidNormalOverTime"));
    }
}

private int _sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = 0;
public int SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice
{
    get { return _sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice; }
    private set
    {
        _sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = 100 * value / 60;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice"));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
}
}
```

**Update:**

Since a change in **Payment** should trigger the update  I would reverse the association between **Payment** and **PaymentDetailInfo**. Then make the binding on **payment.DetailInfo**.

```
public class Payment
{
    public PaymentDetailInfo DetailInfo = new PaymentDetailInfo();

    private int _consideredValidNormalOverTime = 0;
    public int ConsideredValidNormalOverTime
    {
        get
        {
            _return _consideredValidNormalOverTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _consideredValidNormalOverTime = value;
            DetailInfo.SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = _consideredValidNormalOverTime;
        }
    }
}

public class PaymentDetailInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    private int _sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = 0;
    public int SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return __sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice;            
        }
        set
        {
            __sumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice = 100 * value / 60;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice"));
        }
    }    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Now when **ConsideredValidNormalOverTime** is updated **SumOfValidNormalOverTimePrice** is too and automatically updates the source. Implement this for all remaining properties and it should work. Just think about where to put the logic for **SumOfOverPriceConst**. Since it relies heavily on **Payment** maybe you should put it there.

**Original:**

Here's a sample of implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged**. Whenever **Name** changes the target is updated.

```
public class Foo: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region field and properties

    private string _name = String.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: i updated my question, I dont know where I have to call   OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));

Comment: Class Foo only calls PropertyChanged when **Name** is actually changed. Your class only contains getters and no setters apart from **Payment**. Do you want all properties to be updated when **Payment** changes?

Comment: I want to PaymentDetailInfo.SumOfOverPriceConst update whenever each property of Payment update.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your answer but Payment is a database table , I dont want to change it like this.

Comment: Added a final update. Hope you like it otherwise you're on your own ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot,it works. But I had to add 40 properties (number of payment changeable fields) to PaymentDetailInfo. I hope to be a better way to do this,but it works and it's enough for now.thanks again.